# Not able to getting data from one class to another using *.get*()

Tags: java, class, object

I have two classes *RoomDimension* & *RoomCarpet*. Then I have a program that calls these two classes but I am having a problem with the RoomCarpet Class when I try and get a TotalCost for the carpet. It gives me this error when I run *CarpetCalculator*

```
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoomCarpet.getTotalCost(RoomCarpet.java:49)
    at CarpetCalculator.main(CarpetCalculator.java:44)
```

*java:44, this location is the system.out.print at the end that calls the getTotalCost*,

when I try and call the getTotalCost under the RoomCarpet class. I think it has to do with the size.getArea() (when I call it). Below is the code for all classes. Thank all of you for any help.

RoomDimension:

```
public class RoomDimension {
       private double length;
       private double width;

       public RoomDimension(double len, double w){
          length = len;
          width = w;
       }

       public void setLength(double len){
          length = len;
       }

       public void setWidth(double w){
          width = w;
       }

       public double getLength(){
          return length;
       }

       public double getWidth(){
          return width;
       }

       public double getArea(){
          return length * width;
       }

       public String toString(){
           String str = "The length you entered was " + length 
                        + " and the width you entered was " + width;
           return str;
       }
    }
```

RoomCarpet:

```
public class RoomCarpet{
    private RoomDimension size;
    private double carpetCost;

    public RoomCarpet (double cost){
        carpetCost = cost;
    }

       public void setCarpetCost(double cost){
          carpetCost = cost;
       }

       public double getCarpetCost(){
          return carpetCost;
       }

       public double getTotalCost(){
           return size.getArea() * carpetCost; 
       }

      public String toString(){
           String str = "\nYour total area for your room is " + size.getArea()
                        + "\nThe cost of your carpet per square foot is " + carpetCost;

           return str;
       }

    }
```

CarpetCalculator:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class

/**
 * This program demonstrates the RoomDimension & RoomCarpet classes.
 */

public class CarpetCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        double length; // hold room length
        double width;  // hold room width
        double cost;   // hold carpet cost

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("What is your rooms length? ");
          length = keyboard.nextDouble();

          System.out.print("What is your rooms width? ");
          width = keyboard.nextDouble();

          System.out.print("What is the cost of your carpet per square foot? ");
          cost = keyboard.nextDouble();

          RoomDimension testDimension = new RoomDimension(length, width);

          RoomCarpet testCarpet = new RoomCarpet(cost);

          System.out.println(testDimension);
          System.out.println(testCarpet);
          System.out.println("Which means your total cost to carpet the room is " + testCarpet.getTotalCost());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the size variable in RoomCarpet class. You can use setter method or pass through constructor.

try this :

public class RoomCarpet {

```
private RoomDimension size;
private double carpetCost;

public RoomCarpet (double cost){
    carpetCost = cost;
}

public RoomCarpet (double cost,RoomDimension size){
    carpetCost = cost;
    this.size = size;
}

public void setCarpetCost(double cost){
    carpetCost = cost;
}

public double getCarpetCost(){
    return carpetCost;
}

public RoomDimension getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(RoomDimension size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public double getTotalCost(){
    if(size != null) {
        return size.getArea() * carpetCost;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("error size is not define");
        return 0;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String str = "\nYour total area for your room is " + size.getArea()
            + "\nThe cost of your carpet per square foot is " + carpetCost;

    return str;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you never initialize in your *RoomCarpet* the *size* attribute. You should pass a *RoomDimension* object in the *RoomCarpet* constructor:

```
public RoomCarpet (RoomDimension size, double carpetCost){
    this.size = size;
    this.carpetCost = carpetCost;
}
```